# How to select data from multiple tables which are from different databases using Spring data JPA?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Using following link I can able to create multiple data sources in spring.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html

I need to run a query by joining multiple tables which are from different databases(data sources).

Example: 
there are 2 data sources. datasource1 and datasource2
Now I want to join a table from datasource1 with a table from datasource2 like below:

```
Select p from datasource1.Product p Join datasource2.OrderDetail od Where od.productId = p.productId;
```

Can anyone please help me to do this in Spring data JPA. ?

Thanks

Comment: I doubt it is possible. Internally hibernate generates an SQL statement which could be executed in one DB not in both

Comment: You can use two data source: [multiple datasource spring data jpa](https://www.google.com/search?q=multiple+datasource+spring+data+jpa), but joining two tables from different sources... I think don't.

Comment: Try to use this approach: [Using DbLink to access other PostgreSQL Databases](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/44-Using-DbLink-to-access-other-PostgreSQL-Databases-and-Servers.html)  for example

Comment: @Cepr0

I am able to do it (joining two tables) with same type of databases (MySQL) and same credentials using NativeQuery.

Is there any other method to do this ?